# Print Through Terminal Service In vb6 application

Tags: printing, vb6, terminal

i`ve facing a problem with terminal services in my vb6 application.

My program can print reports with Printer.print in remote printers `\\ip\printer`. But when i try to print some report in my application, i receive a error message 'printer error 482'.

I don`t know what can i do to solve this issue...

any idea?

Comment: I had a similar problem with my application until I installed TS print.  http://www.terminalworks.com/remote-desktop-printing

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have a printer installed from at specific user profile.
In the user profile, add a printter and its driver in the control panel / printers.